# "Invalid Label" JSON error from $.POST method

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here is my Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post(
        "admin.php",
        { action: $(this).attr("action") },
        function(data) {
            data = eval("(" + data + ")");
            alert(data);
            //alert(data.message);
        },"json"
    );
});
```

When I run this code, with the basic html page, it works. But when I use the same script in my actual page, it gives "invalid label" error.

My PHP code, to create the json string

```
$return = array("status"=>"true","message"=>"A new ".$this->title." has been added");
$json = json_encode($return);
return $json;
```

The error received at the the errors console at firebug

```
invalid label
[Break On This Error] {"status":"true","message":"A new CMS Type has been added"}
http://localhost/admin/admin.php?menu=2
Line 0
```

Help

Comment: @mrN: It would probably help if you posted up the HTML the script is running agaist.

Comment: What does `test.php` contain? Where does the error come from?

Comment: @mrN: Also, are you 100% sure that the response coming back from your test.php is valid JSON?

Comment: @Brian, if it was not it would not work, it wouldn't work in basic html also i think.

Comment: @pekka, I viewed the error at firebug. and even there I can see the json parameters in `json` section.

Comment: @MrN *where* do you get the "invalid label" error from? The browser? Inside the JSON?

Comment: @pekka, I dont know. It get it at the Errors tab at the Console window of Firebug. It indicate JSON String

Comment: do you `echo` the data? or just `return` it to the void?

Comment: @Salman, at the end, I echo the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your success method above your alert call

```
data = eval("(" + data + ")");
```

JS is interpreting your JSON incorrectly, adding the parenthesis will solve it. More info : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/99-JSON-Minor-But-VERY-Important-Detail-Creating-Syntax-Error-Invalid-Label.htm

Comment: It didn't work, same output Error `invalid label
[Break On This Error] {"status":"true","message":"A new CMS Type has been added"}`

Comment: You put this inside your success function right? do you have a demo page we can look at?